# How to assign class to movieclips in macromedia flash mx 6.0

Tags: flash, class, ide, macromedia

I'm using the Flash MX IDE to add in objects and FlashDevelop for AS3 programming. How do I assign a class to an imported image I've turned into a movieclip?

Opening the library and going into 'linkage' for the object, there is no form field for class or base class like there are in newer Adobe Flash IDEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash MX 6 is a very old product and uses ActionScript 1 - there are no classes in AS1.

Flash CS3 is the earliest version that can handle ActionScript 3.

Comment: What about just the earliest version that accepts assigning classes? Is it Professional 9? I can utilize FlashDevelop to do my AS3 programming + compile.

Comment: Yes, you need to use Pro 9 (CS3) at least.

Comment: +1 icic. Thank you for taking the time to assist me. Looks like I haz no choice =(